# How To Create Custom Post Templates In Genesis Child Theme

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I had searched everywhere for an answer to this question, i would like to create a custom template for "POSTS" not for "PAGES" and no matter how i try to do it in my Genesis child theme is folder it's just not working.

I tried :

```
<?php
/*
*Template Name Posts: Custom Post Template Name
*/
?>
```

And placed this code in my Genesis child theme is folder but i didn't found anything when i tried to create a new post.

Almost all the tutorials out there are explaining how to create a new page template but not posts template.

I would like to know, if its possible to create a new post template?

Comment: you add using like name of your template like 
taxonomy-notice_category.php
single-notice.php  where notice name is taxonomy name.

Comment: I tried renaming the file to single-custom.php and nothing happened.

Comment: http://wpgenesis.blogspot.in/2013/04/custom-page-template-in-genesis-child.html
http://genesistutorials.com/creating-a-custom-template-in-genesis/

Comment: When i put the page template is code, Wordpress founds it very easily and it appears in edit page is right drop down.But when i try to use custom post template instead it's just doesn't do anything.

Comment: ya to also use this lilk. http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/456/using-custom-templates-for-custom-post-types-for-the-genesis-theme-framework

Comment: Thanks alot @ravi but this tutorial is also showing me just how to make a custom PAGE TEMPLATE not custom POST TEMPLATE. :-)

Comment: just to add <?php /* Template Name: My Custom Page */ on your starting of page code see this http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates

Comment: Well, according to the link you shared, i think that i have to create a custom post type and only after that i should create a post template with a name like single-mycustompost.php . I'm not sure if this will work but i will give it a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a solution I found here: http://www.jeffalytics.com/adding-custom-post-types-to-genesis-wordpress-framework/

```
/** Add Custom Post Types */

add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' );
function create_post_type() {
register_post_type( 'the_video',
array(
'labels' => array(
'name' => __( 'Videos' ),
'singular_name' => __( 'Video' )
),
'public' => true,
'has_archive' => true,
'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'videos'),
)
);
}

/**
* add Genesis layout options to custom posts types
*
* @author Brian Lis
* @link http://dev.studiopress.com/genesis-layout-options-for-custom-post-types.htm
*/

add_post_type_support( 'the_video', 'genesis-layouts' );
```

Answer (score 0):

WordPress allows custom PAGE templates by default but this is not the same for single POSTS. Posts use single.php by default. There are some plugins which allow for creating custom post templates but this is not a built in feature in WordPress or Genesis. Or you can use conditional statements to create alternative post templates based on category, tag, post ID etc.

This link helps explain how WordPress deals with page and post templates by default - http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add post type. You can also use page. or put them together like this... post, page
Hope this helps.

```
<?php
/*
 * Template Name: Name Of Template
 * Template Post Type: post
 */ 

// No direct access, please
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit;

get_header(); ?>
```